# How to implement object composition in javascript without empty functions?

Tags: javascript

While developing a new javascript framework for our team, I have been wondering the best way to perform object composition using javascript classes.

For example, I have a simple object called ajax (with many others):

```
function ajax() {
}

ajax.prototype = {
    postJSON: function(url, data, callback) {
        return $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': url,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'data':JSON.stringify(data),
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': callback
        });
    }
};
```

And I have a main object that provide access to every component of the framework and custom options management:

```
function ElDorado() {      
    ...
    this.ajax = new ajax();
    ...
}
```

Finally, I am using a restricted scope:

```
(function(window, jQuery) {
    ... 
    [ajax object]
    ...
    [ElDorado main-object]
    ...
    window.ElDorado = new Eldorado();
})(window, jQuery);
```

So, I have two question:

1. How to avoid the empty ajax "class" function? (Since I dont have any private/public members).
2. What is the best way to access other objects inside the current one?
   For example, now I must do: `window.ElDorado.[other-object]`

Comment: ajax.prototype  can be just var ajax... you don't need "window." if that's the left-had of the expression.

Comment: I don't think so, maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: i'm saying why instantiate a blank object using a constructor and all that overhead when an object literal will work just fine?

Comment: Why do you want to create a custom `ajax` for your `ElDorado` if it doesn't have any custom members? A static, global singleton should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems, that you only use one instance anyways, you could omit the constructor function and just create the object directly:

```
this.ajax = {
    postJSON: function(url, data, callback) {
        return $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': url,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'data':JSON.stringify(data),
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': callback
        });
    }
};
```

And to your second question: If you want to have only one global variable `ElDorado`, then your options are very limited. So calling properties of `ElDorado` in the way:

```
ElDorado.porperty
```

or

```
ElDorado["property"]
```

is pretty much the best option you have.

Comment: But using this approach I must move the ajax declaration inside the Eldorado main object, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can just create your ajax object and save it to an independent variable `var ajax = {...}` and then assign this object as a property to your `ElDorado` object: `ElDorado.ajax = ajax` later on.

Comment: I liked it. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use a constructor inside the object declaration?